# Asp.net Create Rows with Dropdown and populate it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I am creating a asp.net project and have ran into an issue that I am unable to resolve.

I have a gridview that has drop downs in it. I am trying to have it so that when the page loads it runs a sql query and gets the reults (Titles). Then it creates a new grid row for each result and puts in the dropdown box then it selects the item in the drop down.

For instance --

SQL Query select title from oci_project where id='42' this would result in 11.

I would want it to create 11 rows. That have a dropdown in each one and then each one of those drop downs has a title in it from the results.

So

--DD--(Bobs Burgers)
--DD2--(Bobs Meats)
etc.

I have it currently where it is creating drop downs based on the results but I cannot get them to populate.

My code is below for that

```
 protected void BindDepartments(params ListControl[] controls)
    {

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeClock"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (sqlCon)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title from oci_project where client_id='42'", sqlCon))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {

                        adp.Fill(dt);

                        foreach (DataRow projectdata in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            addrecordset();
                        }
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (ListControl ctrl in controls)
                            {
                                ctrl.Items.Add("test");
                                foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                                {
                                    //

                                    ctrl.Items.Add(new ListItem(dtRow["title"].ToString()));


                                }
                                if (ctrl.Items.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    //Insert "-select-" at the first position in dropdownlist
                                    ctrl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "0"));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Insert "-No data-" at the first position in dropdownlist
                                    ctrl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-No Data-", "0"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sqlCon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }


protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ProjectDDL");
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeClock"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT title FROM oci_project where client_id ='42'", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                ddl.Items.Add(dr["title"].ToString());
                ddl.SelectedValue = dr["title"].ToString();


            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: where in your code are you calling the `DataBind()` method for example ctrl.DataBind();` and in theory I think that you should call the Insert method of the `ctrl` after you have issued a `ctrl.DataBind()` also since you are in a `using` you do not need to explicitly call the `sqlCon.Close();`

Comment: My databind is being called at addrecordset() . I will edit my post to show the code.

Comment: how many records are normally in the dropdown by the way.. personally I would change the `(DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];` to use a Session variable like `(DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];` also I would have a `public static DataTable dt{ get; set; }` set in the top of the class. utilize the `if(!IsPostBack){}else{ do the binding of the drop down}` you issue actually looks to be a `PostBack` issue. put a breakpoint in the Page_Load and at the point of when you are expecting to see the Dropdown loaded / bound you should be able to inspect the ddl.Items.Count

Comment: They vary but there are rougly 2000 items in the db that nee to populate into the drop down. However, the drop downs need to select the ones for the records. FOr isntance if there are 11 records returned there needs to be 11 drop downs created that are fully populated from the DB and each one of the drop downs has to be selected to one of the 11 results.

Comment: `2000` items ViewState should be used to hold minimal amounts of data I would use a Session Variable.. why bog down your page with so much potential data.. I totally understand what you're trying to do.. I wonder if a `Repeater` would not better suite your dynamic case..

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157837/dynamically-creating-controls-inside-a-repeater and do a google search for even more examples on `C# aspnet create dropdowns dynamically inside a repeater`

Comment: Hmm not sure if this is what im looking for. Trying to find some good examples to really catch on to this.

Comment: you're creating dropdowns based on a dynamic number of returned records.. Repeater I would think would be the thing to use and or you could look at ItemTemplate too

Comment: I think I have it somewhat figured out. I am at the final stage of figuring it out.
I need to have it now say that foreach dropdownlist in cell 1 of each row in gridview 1. add an item.

I know this will be a foreach{gridviewrow row in gridview1}

But am having trouble coding it out. I know it is only in the column[1] that i need all drop downs.

Comment: Does not seem to work like I thought. I cant seem to put Cells for row.Cells[0]. I already have the Dropdown list in there. Would this create a new one? I think what I need is something like foreach row in gridviews. Find the dropdownlist called "ProjectDDL" then select the value. so like ProjectDDL.SelectedItem = reader[1].tostring(). Something along those lines.

Comment: Unable to see how the below answer would select the string in my dropdown list.

Comment: you would replace the example with your ddl.. I will update..

Comment: I just updated my code at the top. What i forgot to mention was that I added to the RowDatabound and that is where I am trying to accomplish this all at.

Comment: So yeah just trying to select in each one of the drop downs the 1 record is currently processing. Does not seem to work though

Comment: Tried this as well -` foreach(GridViewRow rows in Gridview1.Rows)
                    {
                        DropDownList ddlpro = (DropDownList)rows.Cells[1].FindControl("ProjectDDL");
                        ddlpro.Items.Add(dr["title"].ToString());
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

you would need something like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
{
    ctrl.Items.Add(new ListItem(row.Cells[0].Text)); 
}
```

you could load the ddl in place of where I have string someStrValue

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest incorporating LINQ to access your data source an storing the collection into an List, also incorporating a Javascript framework into your application (i.e jQuery). You can then enumerate over the collection and dynamically create a JQuery Menu with rows and columns, i.e UL and LI

Would save you a considerable amount of time as well as the performance cost and maintainability down the road.